# Prophet fit crashes Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, facebook-prophet

I'm running this piece of code in Jupyter Notebook. All goes well, but the last line always crashes the kernel ("The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."). I ran it in Colab and it works just fine. Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv("./vale3-limpo.csv")
data = data[["Date","Close"]]
data = data.rename(columns = {"Date":"ds","Close":"y"})
from fbprophet import Prophet
m = Prophet(daily_seasonality = True)
m.fit(data)
```

Comment: I've got the exact same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem. But it works after I follow this steps:

step1:Access Anaconda Prompt for the environment that you are working with as admin:

```
conda remove --force fbprophet
```

step2:in your jupyter notebook use

```
pip install fbprophet
```